After adding CancellationToken, it can't find the method
I've updated the interface of my long running method so that it uses a CancellationToken:
public interface IServicoImportacao {

    Task ImportaEquipamentosAsync(int idImportacao,
                                  string nomeUtilizador, 
                                  CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

I'm enqueing the task with the following call:
string jobId = BackgroundJob.Schedule<IServicoImportacao>(s => s.ImportaEquipamentosAsync(idImportacao, nomeUtilizador, CancellationToken.None),
                                                                  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

My job does get enqueued but Hangfire says that it can't find the method when it's hydrating the method call from the database:

However, it does execute the job. Anyone knows what's going on here? Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm using Hangfire 1.8.12 (nuget package).

Is implementation of you Interface public ?  When job definition is an interface hangfire uses TypeInfo.ImplementedInterfaces to find execution method. What happens if you use implemented service to enqueue the job?

Yep, it's implemented as a public method (ie, something like public async Task ImportaEquipamentosAsync(...). The weird thing is that even though it shows that message, the method runs and produces the expected result. This behaviour only started after adding the CancellationToken parameter (which, btw, is passed correctly to the method)
